# MPlayer -wid not working in Swing JFrame

Tags: java, windows, swing, mplayer

I'm trying to embed a video with the MPlayer interface in a Javax.Swing JFrame, but I can't get it to work.

This is what I've done:

```
            Player p = new Player();
            p.setTitle("JMPlayer");
            p.setVisible(true);

            IPlayer player = new IPlayer();
            player.setMPlayerPath("C:\\Java\\MPlayer\\mplayer.exe");
            try {
                try{
                player.open(new File("C:\\Java\\video.mp4"), 
                        "mplayer -wid " + "0x" + Integer.toHexString(Win32.findWindow(null, "JMPlayer")) + 
                        " -vf scale=500:-3 -vo x11 -zoom -ao esd -osdlevel " +
                        "0 -nojoystick -noconsolecontrols -cookies -slave -user-agent NSPlayer " +
                        "-nomouseinput"
                        );
                }catch(Win32.WindowNotFoundException e){

                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Player.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

I also tried doing it with `-wid " + Win32.findWindow(null, "JMPlayer")` but none of them works. Video keeps opening a different window. How can I embed it to the JFrame? Is the Handle wrong?

Comment: Does it need a heavyweight AWT window handle?

Comment: As an alternative, consider using [`MediaPlayer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) (from Java-FX).

Comment: If you know how to embed it to a lightweight componen as a JPanel, how do I get the JPanel HWND @Whome ?

Comment: I want MPlayer because it can play almost any kind of video/audio format @AndrewThompson

Comment: Is `MediaPlayer` limited in format support?

Comment: @FucziFuczi I don't think Swing JWhatever lightweight components have a real Windows HWND window handle. They only live in a Java swing ui context. Old skool AWTWhatever components have an underlying HWND available. SWT UI components may also provide a real window handle.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, it's limited [Media Support](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes)

Comment: @Whome MMm I'll try to do it with AWT components :3

Comment: @FucziFuczi Thanks for the link! I'd looked at the `MediaPlayer` docs and not seen any list of supported codecs/file types (& foolishly presumed it was able to support anything supported on the system), but had not thought to examine the package docs. :P